# Backbone How to Update a Variable or Section Without Re-Rendering the whole page

Tags: backbone.js

I am going to update a section of the html after a click event. But I do not want to rerender the whole page... My code looks like this;

```
<div>OTHER PAGE STUFF I DO NOT WANT TO RE-RENDER</div>

<div>
  <span id="updateThisSection">{{data}}</span>
<div>
```

I want to update the data inside that span after a click event

```
linkClicked : function(e) {
//update the data inside the span here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always have access to the element as a whole through [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) or [`this.$`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) so you can adjust just the parts you need:

```
this.$('#updateThisSection').html('Some new content.');
```

If you have something more complicated than a simple `<span>` then you might want to add a separate sub-view for that part of the view, then you'd bind the sub-view's `render` to the appropriate change event.